# Removing a backslash from a character sequence

Tags: catcodes, detokenize

For indexing I wanted to write a macro `\macroname` that removes leading backslashes from macro names but leaves the names of environments untouched.  That is

```
\macroname{\relax}   -->  relax
\macroname{itemize}  -->  itemize
```

where the `-->` is meant to be read as "expands to".

From my understanding, the following should work:

```
\newcommand\removebs[1]{\if#1\char92\else#1\fi}
\newcommand\macroname[1]{%
  \expandafter\removebs\detokenize{#1}}
```

However, its outcome is

```
\macroname{\relax}   -->  \relax   % literally
\macroname{itemize}  -->  itemize
```

By chance, actually, I found out that if I change the catcode of the backslash to "other" during the definition of the `\removebs` macro, it works:

```
{
  \catcode`\|=0
  |catcode`|\=12
  |global|def|removebs#1{|if#1\|else#1|fi}
}

\newcommand\macroname[1]{%
  \expandafter\removebs\detokenize{#1}}
```

Why is that?  From *TeX by Topic* I'd expect that the comparison made by `\if` is what Philipp Lehman calls "category code agnostic".

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: The problem is that you are comparing a backslash character token with the token `\char` and they are different; `\char92` is an instruction for *printing* the character 92 from the currect font.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Joseph has given a working solution. I'd like to explain what goes wrong with your code.

### First attempt

```
\newcommand\removebs[1]{\if#1\char92\else#1\fi}
\newcommand\macroname[1]{%
  \expandafter\removebs\detokenize{#1}}
```

With `\macroname{\relax}` you get

```
\expandafter\removebs\detokenize{\relax}
```

and then (using `•` to separate tokens and `<space>` do denote a space token)

```
\removebs • \ • r • e • l • a • x • <space>
```

which becomes

```
\if • \ • \char • 9 • 2 • \else • \ • \fi • r • e • l • a • x • <space>
```

and the comparison is between a category code 12 backslash and the token `\char`, which of course leads to false.

The code `\char92` are instruction to *print* character 92 from the current font.

One might correct the code by checking against a real category code 12 backslash:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removebs}[1]{\if#1\@backslashchar\else#1\fi}
\makeatother
```

but the space produced by `\detokenize` after `\relax` would remain.

### Second attempt

```
{
  \catcode`\|=0
  |catcode`|\=12
  |global|def|removebs#1{|if#1\|else#1|fi}
}
```

This works because it just implements the check against a category code 12 backslash, but it's not necessary, as the token is already available as `\@backslashchar` in the LaTeX kernel.

An alternative way, without global definitions and category changes, can be

```
\begingroup\lccode`\|=`\\
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\removebs#1{\if#1|\else#1\fi}}
```

where the only token that is converted to its lowercase equivalent is `|` (to a backslash).

### Proposed code

```
% \makeatletter
% \newcommand{\removebs}[1]{\if#1\@backslashchar\else#1\fi}
% \makeatother
\begingroup\lccode`\|=`\\
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\removebs#1{\if#1|\else#1\fi}}
\newcommand{\macroname}[1]{\expandafter\removebs\string#1}
```

Since all you want is to get the argument letters, it doesn't matter if the first letter in `\macroname{itemize}` has category code 12.

Comment: The problem with an `\if` test here is that it will be true even if the input was not a control sequence to start with (for example if it is the string `\ `).

Comment: Why? With `\macroname{itemize}` we do `\string itemize` and so `#1` is `i` (of category code 12). Of course, if one plays with `\escapechar` things are different. The empty string is disallowed, of course.

Comment: I was thinking of ``{\catcode`/=0/catcode`\\=12/macroname{\}}``, for example.

Comment: In that case nothing would be printed; but the macro is intended for a specific application, so going into all details probably is only a nice exercise. The `\ ` case leaves a space token in the input stream.

Comment: Thanks for also answering my second question (without me asking it, of course) concerning the trailing space token.  To keep things simple, I now went for `\if#1\@backslashchar` and replaced `\detokenize` with `\string`.

Answer (score 12):

TeX works with tokens, and what you need to know is that a control sequence such as `\foo` is not tested by `\if` as a series of characters, but as a single 'unit'. There a a few primitives that will turn control sequences back into single tokens: `\detokenize` does this for a set of tokens, while `\string` does so for a single token. The latter is also available in all TeX versions (`\detokenize` requires e-TeX).

As you observe, detokenizing the input allows you to do a comparison to a category code 'other' `\`. An alternative approach would be to test if `#1` is a control sequence, using the fact that `\ifcat` treats all (unexpanded) control sequences as identical. You can then use `\string` to convert to multiple tokens, and `\@gobble` to remove the very first character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removeabs}[1]{%
  \ifcat\relax\noexpand#1%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble\expandafter\string
  \fi
  #1%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\removeabs{foo}
\removeabs{\bar}
\end{document}
```

---

The above is all fine as long as `\escapechar` is printable and not a space. Using some code from LaTeX3 'translated' back to primitives, you can set things up to be robust for all escape characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removeabs}[1]{%
  \ifcat\relax\noexpand#1%
    \expandafter\removeabs@aux@i
  \fi
  #1%
}
\newcommand*{\removeabs@aux@i}{%
  \romannumeral
    \if\string\ \removeabs@aux@ii\fi
    \expandafter\removeabs@aux@iii\string
}
\newcommand{\removeabs@aux@ii}{}
\long\def\removeabs@aux@ii#1\removeabs@aux@iii{%
  -\number\fi\expandafter\z@
}
\newcommand{\removeabs@aux@iii}[1]{\z@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\removeabs{foo}
\removeabs{\bar}
\end{document}
```

(See the implementation of `\cs_to_str:N` in the LaTeX3 docs for what is going on here!)

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```tex
\def\cwofcs#1#2 \endcs{\ifnum\the\catcode`#1=0#2\else#1#2\fi}
\def\nameof#1{\expandafter\cwofcs\detokenize{#1}\endcs}
```

Test:

```tex
\nameof\relax       % -->  relax
\nameof\itemize     % -->  itemize
```