# How to build a conditional based on a resize paramater

Tags: math-mode, macros, brackets

I would like to define my own macro that accepts an optional parameter such as `\big`, `\Big`, etc that apply that if it is specified, otherwise apply the auto resizing `\left`, `\right` pair.

So, how do I get the following to work for the case where the optional parameter is specified.

I see that if I change the syntax to accept only `\bracc[big]{1, 2}` instead of `\bracc[\big]{1, 2}` (i.e., remove the `\`), then I can use

```
\csname#1\endcsname\{#2\csname#1\endcsname\}
```

which works fine but I would rather be able to specify `\big` (i.e, with the `\`) instead.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bracc}{O{} m}{%
    \IfEq{#1}{}{%
        \left\{#2\right\}%
    }{%
        #1\{#2#1\}%
    }%
}%


\begin{document}
    $\bracc{1, 2}$  
    %$\bracc[\big]{1, 2}$% How to get this case to work?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course _only_ after composing the question do I find a solution.  So am leaving this here in case someone else finds it useful.  I will post an answer if one does not show up in a while.

Comment: Probably a good reference: [Removing a backslash from a character sequence](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42318/5764)

Comment: I don't see the need for `xstring` here: an `o`-type argument and `\IfNoValueTF{#1}{<without option>}{<with option>}` should suffice, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Werner: Thanks. I need that for another problem of mine.

Comment: @cgnieder: Yeah that was the solution I came up with just _after_ composing the question.  You can post it an answer if you want -- don't think there is going to be anything easier than that.

Comment: Will this work in aligned environments with a `\\\` in the argument?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: I can't think of any use case where I would want to allow for a double back slash as a parameter.  Do you have one in mind?

Comment: @PeterGrill: The only time I use `\biggg` etc. is when I have to match delimeters in an aligned environment where the beginning delimiter is on one line and the ending delimiter is on the following line (something really long within the delimiters).  That's exactly where `\left( ... \right)` won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need any packages for this, also you should (effectively) use `\bigl` and `\bigr` if `\big` is specified:

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand\bracc[2][\left]{%
  \ifx\left#1\else\mathopen\fi#1\{%
  #2%
  \ifx\left#1\right\else\mathclose\expandafter#1\fi\}%
}%


\begin{document}
    $\bracc{1, 2}$  

    $\bracc[\big]{1, 2}$% How to get this case to work?
\end{document}
```