# Stupid error caused by doing stupid things

Tags: macros, tex-core

When I was writing my thesis I wrote the following two commands which I found useful (and still do). They are both ways of defining other commands.

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter  
\def\optional #1[#2]#3#4{\newcommand{#1}[#2][@rGUmentmiSSing]{\ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{@rGUmentmiSSing}}{#4}{#3}}}  
\newcommand{\starredcommand}[4][*]{\newcommand{#2}{\@ifnextchar#1{\expandafter #4\@gobble}{#3}}}  
\makeatother
```

They aren't easy to read.  The first one allows me to define a command with an optional argument, where the behaviour of the command is very different if the optional argument is there or not.

The second allows me to define a command with a modifier which I usually use if I have two versions of the same object but one defined on a larger space. For example I have

```
\optional{\foo}[1]{F(#1)}{F} 
\starredcommand{\barr}{\mathcal B}{\mathscr B}
```

So I can write

```
\begin{align}
    \foo &= \foo[x] \\ 
    \barr &\neq \barr*
\end{align}
```

Which would give me the same effect as

```
\begin{align}
    F &= F(x) \\ 
    \mathcal B &\neq \mathscr B
\end{align}
```

I like these commands but they don't play nicely together.
For example if I write `\foo[\bar]` or `\foo[\bar*]` I get over 100 errors, which is bad. It's not to do with the `\@gobble` command eating the bracket. 
`\foo[\bar* 123456789]` Gives me the same thing. And it's not to do with the square brackets. If I define

```
\newcommand{\fine}[1][y]{X^{#1}}
```

then `\fine[\bar]` works exactly as it's supposed to.

I have no idea what's going wrong. It would be great if someone could help.

Here's a follow up question if that one's too easy.  At the moment there's no way of including arguments in my `\starredcommand` If I wanted to give `\barr` an argument I'd normally do something like

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@barr}[1]{\mathcal B^{#1}}
\newcommand{\@barrstar}{\mathscr B^{#1}}
\starredcommand{\barr}{\@barr}{\@barrstar}
\makeatother
```

Which works fine (even with optional arguments or my `\optional` command) but it sort of defeats the point of defining the `\starredcommand` in the first place.
I'd love a version of starred command that could work with arguments but I can't think of a way of doing it.

Comment: why don't you have a look at the `xparse` package, can do very sophisticated argument parsing very easy.

Comment: @ daleif: That would be far too sensible :) It looks like redefining the two commands using that package is probably the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Much as I like your question I feel the title would be better if it described the symptom rather than the cause.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang point taken, but I couldn't think of a concise way of describing this particular problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick attempt with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,mathrsfs}
\NewDocumentCommand\optional{mO{}mm}
 {%
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{o#2}
   {\IfNoValueTF{##1}{#4}{#3}}%
 }
\NewDocumentCommand\starredcommand{O{s}mmm}
 {%
  \NewDocumentCommand{#2}{#1}
   {\IfBooleanTF{##1}{#4}{#3}}%
 }

\optional{\foo}{F(#1)}{F}
\optional{\baz}[m]{Baz with opt #1 and #2}{Baz without opt and #2}
\starredcommand{\barr}{\mathcal{B}}{\mathscr{B}}
\starredcommand[t{+}]{\carr}{\mathcal{C}}{\mathscr{C}}

\begin{document}
$\foo$

$\foo[x]$

$\foo[\barr*]$

$\foo[\barr]$

$\foo[\carr+]$

$\foo[\carr]$

\baz{x}

\baz[Y]{x}
\end{document}
```

However you have to change the way arguments are specified. You see in the example how to use a `+` instead of the `*`; for `\optional` and how to define `\baz` with a mandatory argument (the optional one is always present).

[image]

Comment: Fantastic thank you.  That might have taken days to figure out with just manual. I can probably figure out how to do the arguments using this.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you can have your `\starredcommand` with arguments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\makeatletter
% Following 3 lines thanks to Prof. Enrico Gregorio, from:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42318/
%   removing-a-backslash-from-a-character-sequence
\begingroup\lccode`\|=`\\
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\removebs#1{\if#1|\else#1\fi}}
\newcommand{\@macro@name}[1]{\expandafter\removebs\string#1}
%
\newcommand\starredcommand[5]{%
  \gdef\mname{\@macro@name{#1}}%
  \newcommand#1{\@ifstar{\csname @\mname star\endcsname}
                        {\csname @\mname\endcsname}}
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname @\mname\endcsname[#2]{#3}
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname @\mname star\endcsname[#4]{#5}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\starredcommand{\barr}{1}{\mathcal #1}{1}{\mathscr #1}

\begin{align}
    \barr{C} &\neq \barr*{F}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

FOLLOW UP: Here is a version of your `\optional` command:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
% ...
\def\optional#1[#2]#3#4{%
  \newcommand#1[#2][]{\ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{}}{#4}{#3}}%
}
```

though it is not ideal.  It does allow, per the user's desire, for `\barr` to be an argument of `foo`, except that the `\barr` must be protected, as in

```
\optional{\foo}[1]{F(#1)}{F}
\( \foo = \foo[\protect\barr{Q}] \neq \foo[\protect\barr*{R}]\)
```

[image]

Comment: Also excellent. I'd tried removing the backslashes but given up  as impossible. I'm going to use `xparse` though. It's probably more stable than the code I write.