# Can one avoid typing double quotes in this TikZ-involving macro?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, color

I need to draw many similar complicated colored shapes; I made a macro for them, and it works, but to call it I seemingly have to place several color names in double quotes. Can I avoid this?

The example I produced is a simplified one, what I need is different but the example (hopefully) gives the idea.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\def\sillyexample#1#2{
 \newcount\p
 \foreach\i in {#1}
 {
   \foreach\j in {1,...,\i}
   {
     \pgfmathparse{{#2}[\j+\the\p-1]}
     \node [\pgfmathresult] at (\j+\the\p,0) {\i};
   }
   \global\advance\p by \i
 }
}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \sillyexample{2,3,1}{"red","blue","green","green","cyan","blue"}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As I said this works, the result

[image]

is as expected, the only thing I want is whether I could avoid all these double quotes around color names in the call.

Well, also - since I am asking anyway - can my code be improved in any other way?

Comment: Not if you want to access a nonnumeric array via `pgfmathparse`.

Comment: @percusse Certainly I don't insist on using pgfmathparse or anything else - the only thing I want is to achieve coloring of a given succession of blocks of various shapes with a given sequence of colors

Comment: You could use the xstring package for arrays.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215563/storing-an-array-of-strings-in-a-command/215586#215586

Comment: @JohnKormylo Sorry I looked at the link you provided and also at the xstring documentation but could not figure out how to use it here. Could you explain a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the ultimate solution :)

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcount\positi
\newcount\cumuli

\def\finalexample#1#2{
  \cumuli=0
  \positi=0
  \foreach\kthcolor[count=\k] in {#2}{
    \ifnum\k>\cumuli
      \pgfmathparse{{#1}[\positi]}
      \let\curri\pgfmathresult
      \advance\cumuli by\curri
      \advance\positi by1
    \fi
    \node[\kthcolor] at (\k,0) {\curri};
  }
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \finalexample{2,3,1}{red,blue,green,green,cyan,blue}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here I just create a recursive helper routine `\addquotes`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\sillyexample#1#2{
 \newcount\p
 \foreach\i in {#1}
 {
   \foreach\j in {1,...,\i}
   {
     \pgfmathparse{{\addquotes#2,\relax}[\j+\the\p-1]}
     \node [\pgfmathresult] at (\j+\the\p,0) {\i};
   }
   \global\advance\p by \i
 }
}
\def\addquotes#1,#2\relax{"#1",\if\relax#2\relax\else\addquotes#2\relax\fi}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \sillyexample{2,3,1}{red,blue,green,green,cyan,blue}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Clever!! Is this safe? :)

Comment: There is an upper limit to the recursion depth, but I can't recall if it is 256 or 65536, but hopefully you won't be specifying that large an array.  Other than that, it of course requires comma separation in the list.  But it should be robust.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I would add that I learned recursion techniques from one of David Carlisle's posts long ago.  It was a "game changer" for me.  I am constantly amazed at how many things can be done quickly with a simple recursion macro.

Comment: Well I heard that recursion usually strains resources; but this must be the case when it is harmless...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე If you formulate the recursion improperly, then it certainly strains resources as it enters an endless loop `8^)`

Comment: :)) no but seriously, as a rule recursive things require exponential time and space, no? So they must be used only in cases when the input size is obviously small, like here

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I think it depends on the recursion.  Things like bubble sorts grow at a rate that is more than linear.  In this case, however, the recursion is merely of the form -digest an input, -process the input, -if not done, do it again.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე You can define `\def\addquotes#1,{\ifx,#1,\else"#1",\expandafter\addquotes\fi}` and replace the `{\addquotes#2,\relax}` by `{\addquotes#2,,}`. Now this is not recursion but normal loop, because the next call of `\addquotes` is at the really end of the previous call.

Comment: @wipet I would still call it recursion, since `\addquotes` calls upon itself (in both cases, with a shorter argument, until exhausted).

Comment: @wipet Nonetheless, I find the coding of your "recursion" style interesting, and will study it more (apologies in advance if I *steal* it for future use 8^).

Comment: @wipet One of the reasons I like using `\relax` as a recursion delimiter is that it is not a command likely to appear in a user argument.  Thus, the macro is less likely to be led astray by a typo or user assumption.  Either of our macros works for the proposed argument list, but if a `,,` is introduced in the middle of the list (by accident or by assumption), my macro takes it as a "black" argument, whereas yours breaks.

Comment: You can use `{\addquotes#2,\end,}` and you can test `\ifx\end#1\else...` if you are afraid of `,,`. I can be afraid of `\relax` in the argument list too. But the main difference between your and my recursion is that you call `\addquotes` in the middle of the macro body, i.e. the return pointers and data have to be saved to the stack of this recursion. But if the macro call is at the end of the macro body, TeX does not push new data to the stack but simply replaces previous macro body by the next. From this point of view my solution isn't real recursion. It is used for loop implementation.

Comment: @wipet Thanks for that explanation.  If I understand you correctly, your approach would not be subject to any recursion depth limitation?  If so, that is good to know.

Comment: Yes. The number of items in the processed list is unlimited when my code is used. Because this is not true recursion.

Comment: What makes something count as 'recursion'? (I know what a recursive definition is in logic/maths, but I'm not quite sure how that sense relates to this one?)

Comment: @cfr On the surface, one could call both wipet's and my approaches "recursive", because the routine is self referential.  However, wipet's point might seem like a technicality, but is actually a point of significance.  If `\addquotes` calls itself before it ends (my approach), residue from each call is on "the stack" until the final exit.  It is thus subject to stack limitations.  wipet points out that if `\addquotes` finishes, and then calls itself without argument (his approach), there are no residual pushes on the stack.  Thus the approach is not stack limited.

Answer (score 6):

The LaTeX kernel has features for working on comma separated lists:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcount\p

\def\sillyexample#1#2{%
 \p=0
 \addquotes\sillyexampleargtwo{#2}%
 \foreach\i in {#1}%
 {%
  \foreach\j in {1,...,\i}%
   {%
    \pgfmathparse{{\sillyexampleargtwo}[\j+\the\p-1]}%
    \node [\pgfmathresult] at (\j+\the\p,0) {\i};%
   }%
   \global\advance\p by \i
 }%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\addquotes[2]{%
  \def#1{\@gobble}%
  \@for\next:=#2\do{%
    \edef#1{#1,\string"\next\string"}%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\sillyexample{2,3,1}{red,blue,green,green,cyan,blue}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `\addquotes` macro goes through the given list and builds a new one with each item between double quotes.

Be always careful and place `\newcount` instructions *outside* definitions. With your code, a new counter would be allocated each time the `\sillyexample` macro is called. Also `\p` is not a good name, actually.

Comment: Then I should make this \p zero before reusing it, no?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, I'll add it.

Answer (score 5):

Without using any extra macros or packages, here is a solution which runs in linear time `O(k)`, i.e. linear in `k`, where `k` is the number of colors (equal to 6 in your post). It is all about conditions. The two conditions that I use here are:

```
\ifnum \k > \p{
\ifnum \k < \numexpr\num+\p+1 \relax 
...
```

These conditions precisely pick only the values required for pairing each number with its color. The following results are obtained by running (in order):

```
\lesssillyexample{2,3,1}{red,blue,green,green,cyan,blue}
\lesssillyexample{5,3,2}{red,blue,green,green,cyan,blue,red,blue,green,green}
\lesssillyexample{3,2,3,1,2}{red,blue,green,green,cyan,blue,red,blue,green,green,red}
```

[image]

And here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcount\p
\def\lesssillyexample#1#2{
 \p=0
 \foreach \num in {#1}
 {
  \foreach [count=\k]\kthcolor in {#2}
  {
   \ifnum \k > \p{
    \ifnum \k < \numexpr\num+\p+1 \relax 
     \node at(\k,0)[\kthcolor]{\num};
    \fi}
   \fi
  }
  \global\advance\p by \num
 }
}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \lesssillyexample{2,3,1}{red,blue,green,green,cyan,blue}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is I think **the** perfect solution! I want to accept this one, except that I also like very much another one I already accepted because of that recursion trick. Do you know how to accept two answers? :)

Comment: Here on TeX.SE, when two answers both work, favour the simpler one. This is the rule.

Comment: There's no need for `\the\numexpr` in that context: actually `\ifnum\k<\numexpr\num+\p+1\relax` is better than with `\the` because it avoids two useless expansions (and also premature expansion of `\node`).

Comment: I tend to think the rule is 'accept the one which helped you most', insofar as there is a rule. But, certainly going for the simpler one is recommended, *ceteris paribus*.

Answer (score 3):

I had to modify \getdata a bit to get it to work as a tikz parameter.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcounter{comma}
\newcommand{\colorstr}{}% reserve name
\newcommand{\getcolor}[2][1]% #1 = index, #2 = array name
{\ifnum#1=1\relax\StrBefore{#2}{,}[\colorstr]%
\else\setcounter{comma}{#1}\addtocounter{comma}{-1}%
\StrCount{#2}{,}[\colorstr]%
\ifnum\value{comma}=\colorstr\relax\StrBehind[\thecomma]{#2}{,}[\colorstr]%
\else\StrBetween[\thecomma,#1]{#2}{,}{,}[\colorstr]%
\fi\fi}

\def\sillyexample#1#2{
 \newcount\p
 \foreach\i in {#1}
 {
   \foreach\j in {1,...,\i}
   {
     \pgfmathparse{int(\j+\the\p-1)}
     \getcolor[\pgfmathresult]{#2}
     \node[\colorstr] at (\j+\the\p,0) {\i};
   }
   \global\advance\p by \i
 }
}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \sillyexample{2,3,1}{red,blue,green,green,cyan,blue}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The above comment by John Kormylo, although so far I don't understand it, gave me a hint. He provided a link to an answer to another question; [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216376/48166) to that question inspired this solution:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\def\lesssillyexample#1#2{
 \newcount\p
 \foreach\i in {#1}
 {
  \foreach\j in {1,...,\i}
  {
   \foreach[count=\k] \kthcolor in {#2}
   {
    \ifnum \k = \the\numexpr\j+\the\p\relax 
     \node [\kthcolor] at (\k,0) {\i};
     \breakforeach
    \fi
   }
  }
  \global\advance\p by \i
 }
}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \lesssillyexample{2,3,1}{red,blue,green,green,cyan,blue}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This works, but at the expense of, instead of picking the entry from the required place of the color array, each time starting to scan the array from the beginning until that place is reached, which is very inefficient and inelegant. So although I post this as an answer, I am not going to accept it. Maybe somebody can improve on it or propose something different.

Comment: Notice that you don't need that counter. Use TikZ option `count` on the `foreach` spin.

Comment: @percusse but count only advances by one at each step, and I need to advance it by the ith member of the list

Comment: My mistake. The count was not in your original case in the question.

Comment: @percusse right, this new \k advances by one, but \p jumps by \i