# I would like put a circle in between rows in a table

Tags: tables, tikz-matrix

I would like to create the following where I have circles that "straddle" the `\hline` between rows in a table.  I'm not sure how to do this.  I would also like to be able to put a number in the circles.  Should this be a tikzpicture instead of a tabular?  I really don't know where to start.

[image: table with circles]

The following is what I came up with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
Multiply input by 4 and add 3

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
col1 & Input & Output \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{4em}{Multiple row} & 1 & 7 \\ 
& 2 & 11 & Gap of "4" between rows in a circle\\ 
& 3 & 15 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I guess I'm asking how to do this.  Tikz `matrix` 
was suggested.
I'm also using Overleaf so as was suggested, I had to use an ampersand replacement.

Comment: If table is so simple, as you show on image, you may consider draw it with TikZ picture using library `matrix`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the matrix library.  Can you point to where I can find out about it.  Or show a little example.

Comment: Meanwhile you got nice solution using TikZ `matrix` libraries :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `matrix` which emulates the `c` column with `eqparbox`. The style `center align per column` is (more or less) taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/530708).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newbox\matrixcellbox
\tikzset{center align per column/.style={column #1/.style={nodes={execute at begin
 node={\setbox\matrixcellbox=\hbox\bgroup\strut},
 execute at end
 node={\egroup\eqmakebox[\tikzmatrixname\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn][c]{\copy\matrixcellbox}}}}},
}


\begin{document}
Multiply input by 4 and add 3

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
    nodes={draw,inner sep=2pt,font=\sffamily,inner xsep=1ex},
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,row sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,
    center align per column/.list={1,2}] (mat) {
        Input & Output\\
          1 & 7 \\
          2 & 11 \\ 
          3 & 15 \\ 
};
\path[nodes={circle,anchor=west,inner sep=1ex,draw,semithick,midway}] 
    (mat-2-2.south-|mat.east) -- (mat-3-2.north-|mat.east) node{}
    (mat-3-2.south-|mat.east) -- (mat-4-2.north-|mat.east) node{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with `ampersand replacement` for usage in beamer etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newbox\matrixcellbox
\tikzset{center align per column/.style={column #1/.style={nodes={execute at begin
 node={\setbox\matrixcellbox=\hbox\bgroup\strut},
 execute at end
 node={\egroup\eqmakebox[\tikzmatrixname\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn][c]{\copy\matrixcellbox}}}}},
}


\begin{document}
Multiply input by 4 and add 3

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
    nodes={draw,inner sep=2pt,font=\sffamily,inner xsep=1ex},
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,row sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,
    center align per column/.list={1,2},
    ampersand replacement=\&] (mat) {
        Input \& Output\\
          1 \& 7 \\
          2 \& 11 \\ 
          3 \& 15 \\ 
};
\path[nodes={circle,anchor=west,inner sep=1ex,draw,semithick,midway}] 
    (mat-2-2.south-|mat.east) -- (mat-3-2.north-|mat.east) node{}
    (mat-3-2.south-|mat.east) -- (mat-4-2.north-|mat.east) node{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This compiles by itself but I'm trying to place it in examdesign class I get an ampersand error.
Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.

Comment: @E.Yu Well, this is why you are usually asked to provide us with a minimal working example. Try adding `ampersand replacement=\&` to the options of the matrix, and replace all `&` by `\&` in the matrix.

Comment: Yes.  Sorry.  Lesson learned.  I'll try to make the MWE be in the correct class next time.  Thank you.

Comment: If I make a new table, the column widths seem to affect every other table in the document.  For example if I create a longer first column, all columns of every tikzpicture has the same width.  I don't know how to fix this.  Can you help?

Comment: @E.Yu This is because it was not clear to me that you want to have several of those. One can make the labels unique per matrix in order to avoid that. The simplest way would be if you give the matrices unique names, e.g. `mat1` and `mat2` instead of `mat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}

$\begin{NiceMatrix}[hvlines]
\text{Input} & \text{Ouput} \\
1 & 7 \\
2 &   \\
3 &   
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw ([xshift=3mm]3-|3) circle (3mm) ([xshift=3mm]4-|3) circle (3mm) ;
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]