# Split input at hyphen or space

Tags: macros, strings, parsing

I need to treat input differently, depending on whether it contains a space or a hyphen. That is, the following

```
\foo{foobar}
\foo{foo bar baz}
\foo{foo bar-baz}
\foo{foo-bar baz}
\foo{foo-bar-baz}
```

should become

```
\fooA{foobar}
\fooB{foo}\fooC{bar baz}
\fooB{foo}\fooC{bar-baz}
\fooD{foo}\fooE{bar baz}
\fooD{foo}\fooE{bar-baz}
```

How can I achieve that, i.e., how to define `\foo`?

Comment: algorithm is: fooA = no space or hyphen, fooB = space first, fooD = hypen first,  fooC = remainder after B, fooE = remainder after D ?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of modifying the ordering of the lines in your examples, to (hopefully) make it easier to discern the conditions that lead to outcomes `\fooA`, `\fooB\fooC`, and `\fooD\fooE`. Feel free to revert if you prefer the original layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good place to introduce the `listofitems` package for parsing input.  I had recently introduced a package `getargs`, and almost immediately received an email from Christian Tellechea (http://ctan.org/author/tellechea) pointing out a number of flaws with the package.  But more importantly, my deficient package inspired him to write a better one: `listofitems`, which was even more recently released (http://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems)

It is an extremely powerful and well written package that can perform nested parsing of input lists.  In this example, we don't use nesting, but a neat feature of parsing with two different characters simultaneously: hyphen (`-`) or space ().

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \setsepchar{-|| }%
  \readlist\foobar{#1}%
  \ifnum\foobarlen=1\fooA{#1}\else%
    \ifnum\foobarlen=3%
      \if\foobarsep[1]-%
        \fooD{\foobar[1]}\fooE{\foobar[2]\foobarsep[2]\foobar[3]}%
      \else
        \fooB{\foobar[1]}\fooC{\foobar[2]\foobarsep[2]\foobar[3]}%
      \fi
    \else%
      Invalid argument!
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\def\fooA#1{\textbackslash fooA\{#1\}\par}
\def\fooB#1{\textbackslash fooB\{#1\}}
\def\fooC#1{\textbackslash fooC\{#1\}\par}
\def\fooD#1{\textbackslash fooD\{#1\}}
\def\fooE#1{\textbackslash fooE\{#1\}\par}
\begin{document}
\foo{foobar}
\foo{foo bar baz}
\foo{foo bar-baz}
\foo{foo-bar baz}
\foo{foo-bar-baz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `listofitems` package is even set to work in plain tex:

```
\input listofitems.tex
\def\foo#1{%
  \setsepchar{-|| }%
  \readlist\foobar{#1}%
  \ifnum\foobarlen=1\relax\fooA{#1}\else%
    \ifnum\foobarlen=3%
      \if\foobarsep[1]-%
        \fooD{\foobar[1]}\fooE{\foobar[2]\foobarsep[2]\foobar[3]}%
      \else
        \fooB{\foobar[1]}\fooC{\foobar[2]\foobarsep[2]\foobar[3]}%
      \fi
    \else%
      Invalid argument!
    \fi%
  \fi%
}

\def\fooA#1{FooA[#1]\par}
\def\fooB#1{FooB[#1]}
\def\fooC#1{FooC[#1]\par}
\def\fooD#1{FooD[#1]}
\def\fooE#1{FooE[#1]\par}

\foo{foobar}
\foo{foo bar baz}
\foo{foo bar-baz}
\foo{foo-bar baz}
\foo{foo-bar-baz}
\bye
```

Here's a fun example (in LaTeX) that shows nested parsing.  The `*` form of the `\readlist` macro strips leading/trailing spaces from each list item.  While not the case here, one can invoke `\ignoreemptyitems` or `\reademptyitems` (the default) to decide how empty items in the list should be treated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
% LEVEL 1 PARSE CHAR: \\
% LEVEL 2 PARSE CHAR: &
% LEVEL 3 PARSE CHARS: + OR -
\setsepchar{\\/&/+||-}
\readlist*\foo{
y &= mx + b\\
E &= mc^2\\
y &= Ax^2 + \mathbb{B}x - \mathbb{C }
}

\showitems*\foo\par
\showitems*\foo[1]\par
\showitems*\foo[2]\par
\showitems*\foo[3]... $\foo[3,2]$\par
1st term: $\foo[3,2,1]$\par
Following separator: $\foosep[3,2,1]$\par
2nd term: $\foo[3,2,2]$\par
Following separator: $\foosep[3,2,2]$\par
3rd term: $\foo[3,2,3]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used `foo-bar-baz` etc. with three parts only to illustrate that I want to split at the fist hyphen/space. It ought to work as well with `foo-bar` and also with `foo-bar-baz-oompa-loompa` ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I now understand that you need something more general.  However, it is tough for us to infer the rules you want applied to these other cases.  I think it would help if you edited your question to either give us the exhaustive list of rule cases you need or else to be able to clearly specify a general rule that can be adapted for all cases.

Answer (score 3):

An implementation in `expl3`; if there is a hyphen, we check whether the text before the hyphen contains a space, otherwise we follow the BC route; if there's no hyphens the text is split at spaces and the DE route is followed. No space and no hyphen will follow the A route.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}
 {% call an internal function
  \hagen_foo:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hagen_foo:n
 {% check whether there is a hyphen first
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_hagen_foo_seq { - } { #1 }
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l_hagen_foo_seq = 1 }
   {% no hyphen
    \hagen_foo_spaces:n { #1 }
   }
   {% at least a hyphen
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l_hagen_foo_seq \l_hagen_foo_tl
    \tl_if_in:NnTF \l_hagen_foo_tl { ~ }
     {% the text before the hyphen has a space
      \hagen_foo_spaces:n { #1 }
     }
     {% no space
      \hagen_fooD:V \l_hagen_foo_tl
      \hagen_fooE:f { \seq_use:Nn \l_hagen_foo_seq { - } }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \hagen_foo_spaces:n
 {% check whether there is at least a space
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_hagen_foo_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_hagen_foo_seq \l_hagen_foo_tl
  \seq_if_empty:NTF \l_hagen_foo_seq
   {% no space
    \hagen_fooA:V \l_hagen_foo_tl
   }
   {% at least a space
    \hagen_fooB:V \l_hagen_foo_tl
    \hagen_fooC:f { \seq_use:Nn \l_hagen_foo_seq { ~ } }
   }
 }

% here the auxiliary macros should be defined
\cs_new_protected:Nn \hagen_fooA:n {\texttt{|fooA: #1|}}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \hagen_fooB:n {\texttt{|fooB: #1|}}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \hagen_fooC:n {\texttt{|fooC: #1|}}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \hagen_fooD:n {\texttt{|fooD: #1|}}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \hagen_fooE:n {\texttt{|fooE: #1|}}
% and here the required variants
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hagen_fooA:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hagen_fooB:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hagen_fooC:n { f }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hagen_fooD:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hagen_fooE:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foo{foobar}\par
\foo{foo bar baz}\par
\foo{foo bar-baz}\par
\foo{foo-bar baz}\par
\foo{foo-bar-baz}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It sets up a LaTeX macro named `\foo` which, in turn, calls a Lua function named `HvE` that examines the argument of `\foo` and performs the splitting of the string and the assigning of the substrings to `\fooA`, `\fooB`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function HvE ( s )
   if     string.find ( s , "^%a-%s" ) then
      s = string.gsub ( s , "^(%a-)%s(.*)" , "\\fooB{%1}\\fooC{%2}" ) 
   elseif string.find ( s , "^%a-%-" ) then
      s = string.gsub ( s , "^(%a-)%-(.*)" , "\\fooD{%1}\\fooE{%2}" ) 
   else
      s = "\\fooA{"..s.."}" 
   end
   tex.sprint ( s )
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand\foo[1]{\directlua{HvE(\luastring{#1})}}

% set up test versions of \fooA, \fooB, etc
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\fooA[1]{\textit{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand\fooB[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand\fooC[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand\fooD[1]{\textcolor{purple}{\textsc{#1}}}
\newcommand\fooE[1]{\textsf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example    
\foo{foobar}
\foo{foo bar baz}
\foo{foo bar-baz}
\foo{foo-bar baz}
\foo{foo-bar-baz}
\end{document}
```