# Storing data in a two-dimensional array

Tags: macros, pgfkeys

I'm trying to draw diagrams for the board game Go in TikZ. To reuse board positions in subsequent variations I need a way to store the current board position. I learned from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215563/storing-an-array-of-strings-in-a-command) that two of my options are using `\csname` ... `\endcsname` or `pgfkeys`. As I am using pgfkeys for other things anyways, my question is:

> How would one implement a two-dimensional array with pgfkeys?

I'm open towards solutions not using `pgfkeys`, if you think that's a bad idea. However I would prefer not to use `expl3`, as one of my end goals is to be compatible to Plain TeX, LaTeX and ConTeXt (just like TikZ is)

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but it's worth mentioning that `expl3` is usable with plain and ConTeXt as well as with LaTeX.

Comment: I would use expl3. pgfkeys is ok for user interface but imho not to implement a low-level data structure. Are you sure that a two-dimensional is enough and that you don't need something to store move numbers and perhaps markers?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I plan to have two "arrays". One mapping coordinates to stone color and one mapping coordinates to markers/move numbers. I personally dislike the `expl3` syntax, but I will give it another look.

Comment: I think you will begin to love when you start to write commands to loop over your arrays. expl3 has so many useful tools there. I wished it existed already in the current form when I wrote chessboard and xskak.

Comment: I would just like to point out that 'sgf2dg' is a very powerful tool to draw Go diagrams. It does not exactly do what you ask about here, but it will surely be easier to start from there.

Comment: @fborchers I was using this mainly as an excuse to get deeper into TeX programming. sgf2dg is great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although you gave a preference for pgfkeys, I suspect that is overkill here even if you have pgf loaded for other reasons.

This makes a log of

```
A1 is black and B14 is white
```

from the plain tex

```
\def\setpos#1#2#3{\expandafter\def\csname GO-#1-#2-\endcsname{#3}}
\def\getpos#1#2{\csname GO-#1-#2-\endcsname}

\setpos{A}{1}{black}
\setpos{B}{14}{white}

\immediate\write20{A1 is \getpos{A}{1} and B14 is \getpos{B}{14}}

\bye
```