How to Retrieve the N-th Element from a Comma-Separated List
Given the list one,two,three,four,five
How can I retrieve the third element three from the list?
CODE:
\documentclass{article}

\def\myList{one,two,three,four,five}

\begin{document}
    
    The third element of the list \myList is: three
    
\end{document}


Use the build in Expl3 language. It has a clist data type and features for it. For details see interface3.pdf (\clist_item:Nn \l_maco_clist {3})

thanks for reply, can you give me an example based on my problem above? thx in advance.

You can see many examples of different approaches at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215563/36296

Here is an example using Expl3
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_marco_clist
\NewDocumentCommand\setList{m}
{
  \clist_set:Nn \l_marco_clist {#1}
}
% list counts from 1
\NewDocumentCommand\getItem{m}
{
  \clist_item:Nn \l_marco_clist {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\setList{one,two,three,four,five}

The third element of the list is: \getItem{3}



\end{document}

