# A more elegant version of the \ifnot macro

Tags: macros, tex-core, programming, fun

A TUGboat [article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb21-1/tb66eijk.pdf) of 15 years ago mentions an `\ifnot` macro by David Kastrup whose implementation is:

```
\def\ifnot#1{#1\else
    \expandafter\expandafter\fi
    \iffalse\iftrue\fi}
```

However, this macro looks a bit weird when it is applied to an `\ifSomething` macro, i.e., `\ifnot{\ifeof\stream}`. For the purpose of making TeX code a bit more readable, it might be useful to have a macro which negates the "condition" itself, without the `if` prefix.

Here is a minimal example, which does not work.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@to@be
\begin{document}
  \@to@be@true
  \if@not\@to@be@ Not to be! \fi
  \@to@be@false
  \if@not\@to@be@ Not to be! \fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: You know that e-TeX has `\unless`, right?

Comment: Not quite the same, `\unless\if@I@miss@something` but `\unless\@I@miss@something{would also be a nice approximation}`

Comment: the `\ifnot` macro is designed to be used with an `\if` the article you reference has an example `\ifnot\iftrue` The usage `\if@not\@to@be@` isn't the intended usage and `\@to@be@` hasn't been defined, so it's not clear what you expect it to do

Comment: What about creating a new `\newif` (e.g., named `\newifnot`) so, instead of creating the macros `\iftobe`, `\iftobetrue` and `\iftobefalse` it would create also `\ifnottobe`? I think it would be easier. And may be even appending the code to `\newif` itself.

Comment: How would you link the boolean and it negation? It is easy to define both in the same command, but how would the setting of one of the two correlated variables effect a setting of the other to the negated value?

Comment: @YossiGil I'm not sure of what are you asking, but I already posted an answer. It just appends code `\booltrue` and `\boolfalse` so, apart from setting `\ifbool`, both macros also set the correct `\ifnotbool`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly something like this?  It preserves the OP's desired syntax `\ifnot\tobe`, while at the same time not demanding that `\tobe` be predefined.  Additionally, for those who don't like using `\tobe` without defining it, it allows the alternate syntax `\ifnot{tobe}`, without any changes whatsoever.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% Following 3 lines thanks to Prof. Enrico Gregorio, from:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42318/
% removing-a-backslash-from-a-character-sequence
\begingroup\lccode`\|=`\\
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\removebs#1{\if#1|\else#1\fi}}
\newcommand{\@macro@name}[1]{\expandafter\removebs\string#1}
%
\def\ifnot#1{%
  \edef\tmp{if\@macro@name{#1}}%
  \csname\tmp\endcsname\else
    \expandafter\expandafter\fi
    \iffalse\iftrue\fi}
\makeatother
\newif\iftobe
\begin{document}
  \tobetrue
  \ifnot\tobe Not to be! \else To be!\fi\par
  \tobefalse
  \ifnot\tobe Not to be! \else To be!\fi
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\if@not\@to@be@` highlights the perspective that 
`\@to@be@` is a Boolean variable.

Comment: @YossiGil Please see revision.

Comment: No, it won't work inside other conditionals; try `\ifnum1>1\relax\ifnot\tobe Not to be! \else To be!\fi\fi`

Comment: @egreg I have redacted the answer to reflect the insight.  Thanks for the reality check.

Answer (score 6):

Using e-TeX and assuming `\escapechar` is printable and not a space:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@to@be@
\def\if@not#1{%
  \expandafter\unless\csname
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter i%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter f%
      \expandafter\@gobble\string#1\endcsname
}
\begin{document}
  \@to@be@true
  \if@not\@to@be@ Not to be! \fi
  \@to@be@false
  \if@not\@to@be@ Not to be! \fi
\end{document}
```

(The restriction on `\escapechar` can be lifted if required: see `\cs_to_str:N` in `expl3`.)

Comment: I would say you are fully expended!

Comment: In contrast to David Kastrup's macro, this can't be used inside other conditionals.

Comment: @egreg You mean `\if...` balancing? Well no, but that is implicit in wanting to use `\@to@be@` in place of `\if@to@be@` I'd say. (I would not use either approach myself in real code, but there we go.)

Comment: @egreg I'm mainly trying to show `\unless` here: I'd just use that directly (as intended) in for example `\unless\ifeof` for looping over a file.

Answer (score 5):

Having the full conditional in the argument to `\ifnot` is essential for the macro to work, or it cannot appear in another conditional, because TeX keeps track of `\if...`, `\else` and `\fi` in skipped text.

Assuming the conditional `\iftobe` is defined, your macro should work like

```
\ifnot{tobe}Not to be\else To be\fi
```

Now let's try

```
\iftrue
  \ifnot{tobe}Not to be\else To be\fi
\fi
```

Instead of `\iftrue` think to any other test, for instance `\ifdim\maxdimen>0pt`, that returns true. This gives no problem, because the test is removed and `\ifnot` is expanded, resurrecting the `\iftobe` which will match the first `\fi`.

Now consider

```
\iffalse
  \ifnot{tobe}Not to be\else To be\fi
\fi
```

The test is false, so everything up to and including the matching `\else` (or `\fi`) is skipped. Well, there is `\else`, so `To be\fi\fi` remains in the input stream. Do you see the problem? There's one unmatched `\fi`.

Giving to a macro a name that starts with `\if` doesn't make it a conditional. Only control sequences that are `\let` to a primitive conditional count. So TeX doesn't consider `\ifnot` in the skipped text to be matched by `\else` or `\fi`.

You have to use a real conditional:

```
\newif\iftobe

\def\NOT#1{%
  TT\fi
  \csname if#1\endcsname\else
  \expandafter\expandafter\fi
  \iffalse\iftrue\fi
}

\tobetrue

\if\NOT{tobe}Not to be\else To be\fi

\tobefalse

\if\NOT{tobe}Not to be\else To be\fi

\bye
```

[image]

As an exercise, try

```
\iffalse\if\NOT{tobe}Not to be\else To be\fi\fi
```

and see that no error is raised.

The result is the same as

```
\newif\iftobe

\def\ifnot#1{#1\else
  \expandafter\expandafter\fi
  \iffalse\iftrue\fi
}

\tobetrue

\ifnot{\iftobe}Not to be\else To be\fi

\tobefalse

\ifnot{\iftobe}Not to be\else To be\fi

\bye
```

Of course, David Kastrup's macro is much more powerful, because you can use any conditional in the argument, for instance

```
\ifnot{\ifdim\maxdimen>0pt}TRUE\else FALSE\fi
```

will print FALSE.

Of course, with e-TeX it's easier:

```
\unless\ifdim\maxdimen>0pt TRUE\else FALSE\fi
```

would do the same.

---

An implementation that lifts the restrictions, but is simply useless, in my opinion. The trick is to make `\tobe` equivalent to `\iffalse`, so it will count when `\ifnot\tobe` constructions are in the skipped text of a conditional. Of course, using `\tobe` in the wild is not recommended. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \newifnegatable #1
 {
  \exp_args:Nc \newif { if \cs_to_str:N #1 }
  \cs_set_eq:Nc #1 { if_false: }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \ifnot #1
 {
  \use:c { if \cs_to_str:N #1 }
  \else:
  \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \fi:
  \if_false: \if_true: \fi:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newifnegatable\tobe

\begin{document}

\tobetrue

\ifnot\tobe Not to be\else To be\fi

\iftrue\ifnot\tobe Not to be\else To be\fi\fi

\iffalse\ifnot\tobe Not to be\else To be\fi\fi

\tobefalse

\ifnot\tobe Not to be\else To be\fi

\iftrue\ifnot\tobe Not to be\else To be\fi\fi

\iffalse\ifnot\tobe Not to be\else To be\fi\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

A perhaps more useful implementation (but `\unless` is much easier anyway):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\newdoubleboolean}[1]{%
  \newbool{#1}\newbool{not#1}%
  \csappto{#1true}{\setbool{not#1}{false}}%
  \csappto{#1false}{\setbool{not#1}{true}}%
  \setbool{#1}{false}%
}

\newdoubleboolean{tobe}

\begin{document}

\tobetrue

\ifnottobe Not to be\else To be\fi

\iftobe To be\else Not to be\fi

\tobefalse

\ifnottobe Not to be\else To be\fi

\iftobe To be\else Not to be\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My solution redefines `\newif` macro. The new `\newif\iffoo` declares `\iffoo` and `\ifnotfoo` testing macros and (as usually) `\footrue` and `\foofalse` setting macros. Of course, no packages are needed. The testing macros are skipable in nested `\if..\fi` constructions.

```
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}  
\def\newif#1{\expandafter\newifA\string#1\relax#1}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\newifA\string\if#1\relax#2{%
   \expandafter\newifB\csname ifnot#1\endcsname#2{#1}}
\def\newifB#1#2#3{% #1=\ifnotfoo, #2=\iffoo, #3=foo
   \sdef{#3true}{\let#2=\iftrue \let#1=\iffalse}% 
   \sdef{#3false}{\let#2=\iffalse \let#1=\iftrue}%
   \csname #3false\endcsname
}

%% test:
\newif\iftobe

\tobetrue
\iftobe YES\else NO\fi   
\ifnottobe NO\else YES\fi

\tobefalse
\iftobe YES\else NO\fi   
\ifnottobe NO\else YES\fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another idea.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\gobblethree[3]{} % poor hackish solution expecting usual escapechar
\newcommand*\newifnot[1]
 {\newif#1%
  \csappto{\expandafter\gobblethree\string#1true}%
    {\cslet{\expandafter\newifnotaux\string#1}\iffalse}%
  \csappto{\expandafter\gobblethree\string#1false}%
    {\cslet{\expandafter\newifnotaux\string#1}\iftrue}%
  \csuse{\expandafter\gobblethree\string#1false}}
\newcommand*\newifnotaux[3]{ifnot}

\newifnot\iftobe
\begin{document}
  \tobetrue
  \ifnottobe Not to be! \fi
  \tobefalse
  \ifnottobe Not to be! \fi
\end{document}
```

You could even append code to `\newif` macro so you have all your `\ifnot`s automatically defined.

Comment: How about a version of your `\newifnot` whose name is `\new@boolean`, or if you prefer the more standard convention, `\newboolean`. The \new@boolean@` command could use the `\removebs` (see @Steven B. Segletes answer) macro to define a new boolean variable, allowing, e.g., `\new@boolean\@tobe@`, and then `\@tobe@true`, `\@bobe@false`, `\if@tobe@` and `\if@not@tobe@`?

Comment: That's *exactly* what it does, except that `\if@not@tobe@` is `\ifnot@tobe@`. If you want to have a `@` between `if` and `not`, just edit `\newifnotaux`. It would be much easier if you used `\newwhatever{@tobe@}` rather than `\newwhatever\if@tobe@` (which is exactly what the last edit of egreg does), but I used the same syntax of `\newif\if@tobe@`.