# Alphabetical ordering of items composed of macros in itemize

Tags: macros, formatting, sorting

This is a continuation of the topic:
[Alphabetically display the items in itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121489/alphabetically-display-the-items-in-itemize)

But sadly I don't have the necessary reputation to comment there.

Method proposed by @Werner works perfect, even when you need to display formatted text in your list.
But I have an additional issue: I need to sort items which contain formatting, and I need to be able to edit these items' text and formatting. Hence I use macros, So I can't use the trick with the optional  containing the plain text.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}% http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool
\newcommand{\sortitem}[1]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#1}% Add entry as description
}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}% Create new/discard old list
}{%
  \DTLsort{description}{list}% Sort list
  \begin{itemize}%
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description}{%
      \item \theDesc}% Print each item
  \end{itemize}%
}
\begin{document}

% I need to be able to edit these items and their formatting without changing the rest of my code
\newcommand{\firstitem}{ISDYNSTP:  Is dynamic time step used ?}
\newcommand{\seconditem}{\textit{ISCDCA:}}
\newcommand{\thirditem}{\textbf{MVAR}}
\newcommand{\fourthitem}{IS2TL}

Default:
\begin{itemize}
  \item \firstitem
  \item \seconditem
  \item \thirditem
  \item \fourthitem
\end{itemize}

Sorted:
\begin{sortedlist}
  \expandafter\sortitem\expandafter{\firstitem}
  \expandafter\sortitem\expandafter{\seconditem}
  \expandafter\sortitem\expandafter{\thirditem}
  \expandafter\sortitem\expandafter{\fourthitem}
\end{sortedlist}

\end{document}
```

I added the `\expandafter` so the macros are expanded, so items are well sorted, unless they have some formatting like `\textbf`, then they are just displayed first without any alphabetical ordering.

Any idea ?

Comment: I think that the easiest way would be to add the items to the list first and then print the list. That way, you could add a sort key to the definition which would not include problematic mark-up. **Datatool** is designed to handle data from e.g. `.csv` files. It is not, as far as I can tell, intended for processing stuff with TeX macros in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to use @Werner's method without having to write myself plain text versions of the macros I was trying to sort.

It uses `\pdfstringdef` from `hyperref` package to extract the plain text form of the macros.

Be careful with this method, because it's not safe with any formatting, for example I had to define an exception for `\textcolor`. It also acts weirdly with spaces, but that isn't a problem in my case.

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\sortitem}[2][\relax]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
  \ifx#1\relax
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{sortlabel}{#2}% Add entry sortlabel (no optional argument)
  \else
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{sortlabel}{#1}% Add entry sortlabel (optional argument)
  \fi%
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#2}% Add entry description
}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}% Create new/discard old list
}{%
  \DTLsort{sortlabel}{list}% Sort list
  \begin{itemize}%
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description}{%
      \item \theDesc}% Print each item
  \end{itemize}%
}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\textcolor#1{}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\first}{ISDYNSTP: Is dynamic time step used ?}
\newcommand{\second}{\textcolor{blue}{ISCDCA:}}
\newcommand{\third}{\textbf{MVAR}}
\newcommand{\fourth}{IS2TL}

List of items :
\begin{itemize}
\item \first
\item \second
\item \third
\item \fourth
\end{itemize}
\bigskip

\pdfstringdef\firstplain{\first}
\pdfstringdef\secondplain{\second}
\pdfstringdef\thirdplain{\third}
\pdfstringdef\fourthplain{\fourth}

List of "plain" items :
\begin{itemize}
\item \firstplain
\item \secondplain
\item \thirdplain
\item \fourthplain
\end{itemize}
\bigskip

Sorted items (without expandafter) :
\begin{sortedlist}
  \sortitem[\firstplain]{\first}
  \sortitem[\secondplain]{\second}
  \sortitem[\thirdplain]{\third}
  \sortitem[\fourthplain]{\fourth}
\end{sortedlist}
\bigskip

Sorted items (with expandafter) :
\begin{sortedlist}
  \expandafter\sortitem\expandafter[\firstplain]{\first}
  \expandafter\sortitem\expandafter[\secondplain]{\second}
  \expandafter\sortitem\expandafter[\thirdplain]{\third}
  \expandafter\sortitem\expandafter[\fourthplain]{\fourth}
\end{sortedlist}
\bigskip

\end{document}
```

As you can see if you try out that code sample, you need to use `\expandafter` to get the correct result.

Following is a more complex example which can deal with a list of macros to sort.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\sortitem}[2][\relax]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
  \ifx#1\relax
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{sortlabel}{#2}% Add entry sortlabel (no optional argument)
  \else
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{sortlabel}{#1}% Add entry sortlabel (optional argument)
  \fi%
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#2}% Add entry description
}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}% Create new/discard old list
}{%
  \DTLsort{sortlabel}{list}% Sort list
  \begin{itemize}%
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description}{%
      \item \theDesc}% Print each item
  \end{itemize}%
}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\textcolor#1{}}

%%%  Lists handling %%%

\newcommand{\addlocallist}{\listadd\locallists@dummy}
\NewDocumentCommand{\parsespacelist}{ >{\SplitList{ }} m } {%
    \ProcessList{#1}{\addlocallist}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\parsecommalist}{ >{\SplitList{,}} m } {%
    \ProcessList{#1}{\addlocallist}%
}
\newcommand{\parselist}[3][,]{%
    \renewcommand\addlocallist{\listadd#3}%
    \undef#3%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{ }{\parsespacelist{#2}}{\parsecommalist{#2}}%
}

\newcommand{\addtosortedlist}[1]{%
    \pdfstringdef\plaintexttemp{#1}%
    \expandafter\sortitem\expandafter[\plaintexttemp]{#1}
}%

\newcommand{\ruleslist}[1]{%
    \parselist[,]{#1}{\locallists@ruleslist}%
    \begin{sortedlist}%
        \forlistloop{\addtosortedlist}{\locallists@ruleslist}%
    \end{sortedlist}%
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\first}{ISDYNSTP: Is dynamic time step used ?}
\newcommand{\second}{\textcolor{blue}{ISCDCA:}}
\newcommand{\third}{\textbf{MVAR}}
\newcommand{\fourth}{IS2TL}

List of items :
\begin{itemize}
\item \first
\item \second
\item \third
\item \fourth
\end{itemize}
\bigskip

Ordered list :

\ruleslist{\first, \second, \third, \fourth}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to add structure; a command `\newitem` (supplemented by `\useitem`) will maintain separate the actual data from the formatting instructions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sortitem}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\@sortitem{\expandafter\@sortitem}}

\newcommand{\@sortitem}[2]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#1}% Add entry as description
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{formatting}{#2}% Add formatting info
}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}% Create new/discard old list
}{%
  \DTLsort{description}{list}% Sort list
  \begin{itemize}%
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description,\theForm=formatting}{%
      \item \theForm{\theDesc}}% Print each item
  \end{itemize}%
}
\newcommand{\newitem}[3]{\newcommand#1{{#2}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\useitem}[1]{\expandafter\@useitem#1}
\newcommand{\@useitem}[2]{#2{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% I need to be able to edit these items and their formatting without changing the rest of my code
\newitem{\firstitem}{ISDYNSTP:  Is dynamic time step used ?}{}
\newitem{\seconditem}{ISCDCA:}{\textit}
\newitem{\thirditem}{MVAR}{\textbf}
\newitem{\fourthitem}{IS2TL}{}

\useitem\seconditem % just for example

Sorted:
\begin{sortedlist}
  \sortitem\firstitem
  \sortitem\seconditem
  \sortitem\thirditem
  \sortitem\fourthitem
  \sortitem{AAAAfirst}{\textsc}
\end{sortedlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer. However it does not solve entirely my issue, I wasn't clear enough. Your solution and @Guho 's one both require me to type myself a plain version of the item somewhere, and I can't do that, because I already have a huge dictionnary of macros, and I can't edit it.

Isn't there a way to extract the plain text from a macro ? For exemple a `\extractplain` macro that would be able to automatically output `MVAR` when `\extractplain{\thirditem}` is called ?

That would allow to feed @Werner 's `\sortitem` optional argument, for example, and would work for me.

Comment: I found something working, I posted it as an answer !

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the second part of @Werner's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121492/89497) to your linked question with the optional plain text sort, the following might suit your needs.

For each formatted command you will have to define a separate command with the same name but with the suffix `plain` that defines the plain text used for sorting. The `\sortitem` command has been modified so that if one argument is passed, it is first tested to see if it is a command (courtesy of an adapted form of this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42337/89497) by egreg). If so, the `plain` variant is tested and, if it exists, that is used as the sort label. If not, the passed argument is used.

Your MWE (with a few additional test entries):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}% http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool

%from egreg at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42337/89497
\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`\|=`\\
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\removebs#1{\if#1|\else#1\fi}}
\newcommand{\macroname}[1]{\expandafter\removebs\string#1}

%adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42337/89497
\newif\ifisamacro
\begingroup\lccode`\|=`\\
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\nameifmacro#1#2\nil{\if#1|#2\else\relax\fi}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\sortitem}[2][\relax]{%
    \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
    \ifx#1\relax%no option passed...see if #2 is a macro and has a plain-text variant
        \edef\testifmacro{\expandafter\nameifmacro\string#2\nil}%test if it is a macro. will be the name if it is a macro, \relax if not
        \expandafter\ifx\testifmacro\relax%then it is not a macro...
            \DTLnewdbentry{list}{sortlabel}{#2}%
        \else%it is a macro
            \expandafter\ifcsname\macroname{#2}plain\endcsname%then it has a plain text option defined              
                \edef\rslt{\noexpand\DTLnewdbentry{list}{sortlabel}{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandonce\expandafter\csname\macroname{#2}plain\endcsname}}%
            \else%no plain text option...expand macro once to pass contents for sorting
                \edef\rslt{\noexpand\DTLnewdbentry{list}{sortlabel}{\expandonce#2}}%
            \fi
            \rslt%execute the \DTLnewdbentry command
        \fi
  \else
    \DTLnewdbentry{list}{sortlabel}{#1}% Add entry sortlabel (optional argument)
  \fi%
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#2}% Add entry description
}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}% Create new/discard old list
}{%
  \DTLsort{sortlabel}{list}% Sort list
  \begin{itemize}%
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description}{%
      \item \theDesc}% Print each item
  \end{itemize}%
}
\begin{document}

% I need to be able to edit these items and their formatting without changing the rest of my code
\newcommand{\firstitem}{ISDYNSTP:  Is dynamic time step used ?}
\newcommand{\seconditem}{\textit{ISCDCA:}}
\newcommand{\thirditem}{\textbf{MVAR}}
\newcommand{\fourthitem}{IS2TL}

%append plain to the end of the associated macroname to define the plain text variant for it.
\newcommand{\seconditemplain}{ISCDCA:}
\newcommand{\thirditemplain}{MVAR}

Default:
\begin{itemize}
  \item \firstitem
  \item \seconditem
  \item \thirditem
  \item \fourthitem
\end{itemize}

Sorted:
\begin{sortedlist}
    \sortitem{b}
    \sortitem{\firstitem}
    \sortitem{\seconditem}
    \sortitem{seconditem}
    \sortitem{\thirditem}
    \sortitem{\fourthitem}
    \sortitem{A}
\end{sortedlist}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image: sorted results]

The initial test was included so that `\sortitem{seconditem}` would *not* be sorted according to the contents of `\seconditemplain`. I have tried to limit expansion of the arguments and referenced commands to their contents for the `sortlabel` to keep it from breaking. As such, if no `plain` variant is provided, then they will be sorted according to the `\` at the start of the contents (as far as I can tell) and will appear at the beginning of the list. This also keeps it from breaking if the `plain` commands are not actually plain text. Note that it will break if you have spaces between the opening brace and the command (e.g., `\sorteditem{ \seconditem}`).

A nice addition would be to wrap the creation of both formatted and plain commands into a single call, for example:

```
\newcommand{\newsorteditem}[3][\relax]{%
    \ifx#1\relax\else
        \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#3plain\endcsname}{#1}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#3\endcsname}{#2}}%
```

which would be called like `\newsorteditem[plain text]{formatted text}{commandname}`.

Comment: Hey ! Thank you for your input. However I have an additional issue I described in @egreg 's post.I don't think your solution would work, since I have to define the plain version of my macros somewhere, and I don't want to do that. I would need `\_macro_plain` to be automatically fed.

Comment: I found something working, I posted it as an answer !