# Use of 'newcommand' that modifies the names of invoked commands before executing them

Tags: macros

I was wondering the other day about the following. Suppose I have two commands, `\mycommand` and `\mycommandSpecial`:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}
    {A simple phrase.}
\newcommand{\mycommandSpecial}
    {A special phrase!}
```

Suppose now that I also have another command, along the lines of the following (which of course does not work, but it gives you a sense of what I am looking for):

```
\newcommand{\mynewcommand}[1]
    {First this one: #1 -- and then the special one: #1Special}
```

My hope is that if I now type `\mynewcommand{\mycommand}` I would get the following output:

> First this one: A simple phrase. -- and then the special one: A special phrase!

I want, as you can see, to have only *one* argument for `\mynewcommand` (because of `[1]`), but invoking *both* of the other commands, making use of their similar names, as the special command has only something added to its name.

Regardless of what I want to achieve (and whether this is reasonable), I was wondering generally whether LaTeX can do this, somehow modifying the commands within a command *before* executing them.

I was looking into `\expandafter` and `\csname … \endcsname` and tried something along the lines of:

```
 \newcommand{\mynewcommand}[1]
    {First this one: #1 -- and then the special one: \expandafter#1\csname#1Special\encsname}
```

But it does not work as you will see immediately.

Comment: Why don't you post a minimal working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want as I can understand it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mycommand}
    {A simple phrase.}
\newcommand{\mycommandSpecial}
    {A special phrase!}

\newcommand{\executeBoth}[1]{Here is firs: ``\csname#1\endcsname''\par Here is second: ``\csname#1Special\endcsname''}

\newcommand{\executeSelected}[1][0]{\ifnum#1=0 Fisrt command selected:``\mycommand''\else Second selected: ``\mycommandSpecial''\fi}

\newcommand{\myscommand}[1]
    {A simple phrase. And a \emph{#1}}
\newcommand{\myscommandSpecial}[1]
    {A special phrase! And no \emph{#1}}

\newcommand{\executesBoth}[2][pig]{Here is firs: ``\csname#2\endcsname{#1}''\par Here is second: ``\csname#2Special\endcsname{#1}''}

\newcommand{\executesSelected}[2][0]{\ifnum#1=0 Fisrt command selected:``\myscommand{#2}''\else Second selected: ``\myscommandSpecial{#2}''\fi}


\begin{document}

One command will execute both:

\executeBoth{mycommand}\vspace{20pt}

Next command without argument will execute first:

\executeSelected\vspace{20pt}

Next command with optional non zero will execute second:

\executeSelected[8]\vspace{40pt}




{\bfseries with arguments}\vspace{10pt}

One command will execute both:

\executesBoth{myscommand}\vspace{20pt}

Next command without argument will execute first:

\executesSelected{ball}\vspace{20pt}

Next command with optional non zero will execute second:

\executesSelected[8]{ball}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: please note that this will *not* give an error or warning if you misspell the name of a command

Comment: @jakun it is just the basic idea... We can expand it with `\ifcsname` but I thing the OP needs just a way to start and to see of such way is useful for him. Usefull comment although.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this via `\csname`...`\endcsname` or `\@nameuse`. However, since you're passing a control sequence rather than a string, you'll have to [`remove` the `b`ack`s`lash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42337/5764) first:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42337/5764
\begingroup\lccode`\|=`\\
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\removebs#1{\if#1|\else#1\fi}}
\newcommand{\macroname}[1]{\expandafter\removebs\string#1}

\newcommand{\mycommand}
  {A simple phrase.}
\newcommand{\mycommandSpecial}
  {A special phrase!}
\newcommand{\mynewcommandA}[1]
  {First this one: #1{} -- and then the special one: \csname\macroname{#1}Special\endcsname}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mynewcommandB}[1]
  {First this one: #1{} -- and then the special one: \@nameuse{\macroname{#1}Special}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb|\mycommand|: \mycommand

\verb|\mycommandSpecial|: \mycommandSpecial

\verb|\mynewcommandA{\mycommand}|: \mynewcommandA{\mycommand}

\verb|\mynewcommandB{\mycommand}|: \mynewcommandB{\mycommand}

\end{document}
```

`\@nameuse` is similar to `\csname`...`\endcsname`, but requires a `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair if used in a regular document. Also, no checking is performed whether the macro passed to `\mynewcommand` exists. `\csname`...`\endcsname` defaults to `\relax` if the resulting macro doesn't exist and therefore will print nothing. One can build in a check, if needed.

---

A somewhat more intuitive alternative to `\macroname` could be to `\@gobble` the `\`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\macroname}[1]{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Oh! How very interesting! I am slightly puzzled though that the solution apparently is quite complicated (see the first lines about `\begingroup …` and the definition of `\macroname`). Does this mean that modifying command names prior to their execution is not part of the standard toolbox of latex? I.e. there are no readymade commands that do this?

Comment: @ClintEastwood: Construction of control sequences is done using `\csname`...`\endcsname`. However, your input requires the deconstruction of a control sequence before constructing it the "special" version.

Comment: @ClintEastwood: Using `\csname\macroname{#1}\endcsname` was superfluous. It just defaults to `#1`; I've updated my code for that.

Comment: ahh, I see now. thanks for clarifying this. So if the input were without a backslash, then one would not have to reconstruct first, right? (So much I gathered now from your response and the alternative solution by koleygr.)

Comment: @ClintEastwood: Indeed. It's easier to work with `\mynewcommand{mycommand}`.

Comment: @Werner why not using a simple `\@gobble` instead of `\removebs`? That would reduce the complexity of the first few lines a lot.

Comment: @jakun: Have you tried using your `\@gobble` suggestion?

Comment: @Werner yes, I have tried it. it works.

Comment: I think the `{}` after `#1` are not needed. The following space will not be gobbled because the gobbling of spaces after control words happens *before* `#1` is replaced by the control word.

Answer (score 2):

This screams for `*`-variant.

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{s}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{A simple phrase.}{A special phrase!}%
}

\newcommand{\mynewcommand}[1]{%
  First this one: #1 -- and then the special one: #1*%
}
```

The first command can be called `\mycommand` or `\mycommand*`.